# How to access file from HAML file upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, haml

I have a Rails app in which I am using HAML for markup. In one haml file (bob.html.haml) I have the following

```
= form_tag bob_scorecard_dashboard_index_path :multipart=>true  do
  = file_field_tag 'file[]', multiple: true
  = submit_tag "Import"
```

In the associated controller I have

```
 def bob
    pp 'Do process logic on this file now... '
    file = params[:file]
    if (!file.nil?)
      pp 'hey buddy'
      pp file[0]
      #pp file[1] #This would show the second file uploaded, etc.
      #pp file[2] #Third file uploaded... and so on
    end
```

I can see that whenever I hit upload (the button labeled 'Import'), my method 'bob' gets called. What I would love is for the files I attached in the file upload utility rendered by HAML to be accessible/to be able to manipulate them in any way. Currently params[:file] contains an array of Strings... those strings are the filenames of what the user uploaded. But the actual files are not saved in any temp location, and, as such, can not be manipulated in any way. It seems to me perhaps the HAML piece is not doing it's job... no file is being uploaded to the server that the application is being run on when I hit Submit, so far as I can tell. Instead, I just get a String of what the filename that they uploaded was... but no actual file.

This is a legacy app for which I cannot use Paperclip or Carrierwave - useful utilities I've used in other projects. If at all possible, I want to upload and manipulate the uploaded files in 'pure' ruby and HAML, alone. Is this possible?

Comment: Weird. Should have worked. Try this, though: `= file_field_tag :files, multiple: true`, I'm not sure about that array syntax.

Comment: Also, post what `p params` looks like.

Comment: pp will result in the string filename of whatever I passed into the uploader. So if I uploaded a file 'my_file.txt'. My pp statement down there will print out 'my_file.txt'. Issue is that my_file.txt doesn't exist anywhere in any of the application folders. It wasn't actually uploaded anywhere.

Comment: And likewise, with that syntax above, if I shift-click and upload multiple files, I can access them in the controller as file[0], file[1], file[2] etc. printing these values gives me the respective filenames that I selected for upload. But the missing piece is... the files are not actually uploaded to the application. The files I selected cannot be found anywhere in the rails project's folders. In the controller, if I try to manipulate file[0]/1/2 etc. as if it were a file... ruby craps out... reason being it is just a string that is the filename of what I uploaded, not the source.

Comment: I believe you here, but you know the saying: "one line of code is worth a thousand words". So next time someone asks you to post `p params`, you post `p params`. People can make mistakes in their english, but the code doesn't lie :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Whoop... had no idea p params was a thing. I uploaded three files and output is: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EHilJWT9cA5J4l5OK/Zq9OAUr09Vul9rRC/KLZGMyTMW76ezzkm1BZKalNSRbN8ZF1y7yRefMSw9yuOwyFyowQ==", "file"=>["AF_CSX_DISTRIBUTE_NUMBERS.xlsx", "AF_CSX_DISTRIBUTE_NUMBERS_V2.xlsx", "Asset_Categories.csv"], "commit"=>"Import", "multipart"=>"true", "controller"=>"scorecard_dashboard", "action"=>"bob"}. It does definitively tell me that it is just storing a string array of filesnames without any processing or piece that has to do with actual files.

Comment: Yep, just as you described. Is this form posted via ajax, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor mistake on your part. That form declaration should be this:

```
= form_tag bob_scorecard_dashboard_index_path, :multipart => true do
                                             ↑
```

What you had evaluated to something like '/dashboard/scorecard/bob?multipart=true`. It was a regular query string param instead of a form option.

Comment: See, that's why you post debug output as asked, instead of describing it :)

Comment: This was exactly it - much thanks! You're the man. Thanks for guiding me about - now I know about `p params` and will definitely use that in any future debugging to grab params array.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade: Just so you know, `p` is a regular ruby method and you can print all sorts of objects with it. `p obj` is roughly equivalent to `puts obj.inspect`